# /etc/hosts not working when connected to WIFI MacOS

Tags: macos, dns, hosts

Any changes to the /etc/hosts is ineffective when connected to WIFI,
When I disconnect it starts taking effect.

I have tried `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be from VPN software I had installed, uninstalled it and reconnected the WIFI and it seems fine.